# Why is my Blogger theme two coloured and have this ugly text in the background?

Tags: blogger, css, blogger-themes, blogger-templates

Why is my blog's background two coloured and where does this text (see the red arrow) come from? I want the background to be one colour and the text to disappear.

(If possible I would like to hide the HTML/Javascript gadget in the sidebar but if I do, the Javascript is not loaded. Any workaround?)

[image]

Here is a screenshot of my setup. As you can see, I have hidden almost all elements.

[image]

The address is https://milkostnader.blogspot.com/ but this is not an encouragement to visit it - just in case someone wants to look that source or something.

As you can see, this is not really a blog but rather a form with a Javascript (presenter.js) connected where you can enter different numbers and some calculations are made. Are there better platforms than Blogger for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

You theme is two-coloured because you have chosen (or just accepted the default) of Contempo as a theme.

I suggest going to the Theme (not layout) tab, and scrolling down to Simple:   choose the one of these themes that has a white background, then click Apply.   Then Customise, and go to the layout sub-tab within Themes:   here you can choose a body-layout with no sidebars.

In the Posts tab, create one post, edit it in HTML view and put your Javascript code in there.

Then, in the Layout tab, remove ALL the gadgets, or put them in the footer.